java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider
I need some help with a project migration from Java 8 to Java 17. I've updated all deprecated libraries to those compatible with Java 17. The project builds successfully in IntelliJ, but when deploying on Tomcat 9, I encounter the following error:
[2024-06-19 06:02:58,822] Artifact test:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

19-Jun-2024 18:03:00.206 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [manageApp]

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1782)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider not present
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:47)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:89)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)

Please note, I have already changed my javax related libraries to jakarta. Any insights on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

does this help to answer your question as well? Error starting child

According to the upvoted answer to this question (tomcat-9-jdk-14-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-ws-webserviceref) you will want to add jakarta dependencies to the Tomcat lib directory. Note you would want to have the Jakarta rather than the javax libraries, since that is what you compile your project with.

I was finally able to resolve this by adding the following JARs to Tomcat's lib folder (JAX WS API and all its dependencies):


thanks for your response but I already added all the jars in tomcat lib folder

Hello. Please post the names of the files you added in the lib folder. Maybe there has been some mistake or there is something missing. Also consider posting your pom.xml (assuming you are using maven).

hi now I am getting this exception    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:426) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Unresolvable class definition for NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]

Hi again, please update your question (edit it), to include the message you posted here and other relevant changes you made.

One thing I want to tell you I read somewhere there is compatibility issue java17 with tomcat 9 so I shift to tomcat 10, and also my project is not maven

You are probably using a wrong dependency or a wrong version. Are you using Gradle? Can you post your dependencies, in the system you are using?

A cursory search turned up two NamespaceHandlers, one for package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml and another for org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring Once you know which one you want, make sure there are no mixed-up deps.
